# $\{u_{n}\}$ harmonic and converging uniformly to $u \Rightarrow $ $u$ harmonic

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, harmonic-functions

Let $A$ be an open set, $\{u_{n}\}$ a sequence of harmonic functions on $A$, converging to $u$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$ . Then $u$ is harmonic on $A$.

Any hint ?

Comment: Mean value property? Also, Poisson integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Gauss Mean Value Theorem for Harmonic Functions: A function $u :\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is harmonic if and only if 
$$
u(x_0)=\frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r(x_0)}u(x_0+h)\,dh
$$
for every $\overline{B}_r(x_0)\subset\Omega$.

Then uniform convergence passes is both sides of the above.